# CartoView Error

Tags: python, postgresql, django, geonode, web-gis

I've installed CartoView on Windows 7 by default instruction. I've changed Postgres to my own DB (It was problem with default DB from install package). CartoView doesn't start with this error:

[image]

I see, that problem is Django, but have no idea how to solve it.
When I try to run listed script I get python error:

[image]

Comment: Which version of cartoview windows installer ?? Is this error produced when you choose default db settings in the wizard??

Comment: I've downloaded latest Windows version, as default db I used default settings and tried already existing Postgre db - no results.